# How to give Common path to video

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working in project in which I have used vlc plugin v2. the path for my video is

```
axVLC.playlist.add(@"D:\My Project\Science\Resources\myvideo.mp4");
        axVLC.playlist.play();
```

now the problem is when I build the project and give it to someone and he/she install it on his/her computer , it show exception that video path is wrong. I am sure that path is not suitable as my the video path in my project is D:... and he/she installed it on C. 
So my question is that is there any way to give it common path by which user don`t face such kind of error

Comment: Do you really want to play only this one video? If not I would implement a drag&drop routine and maybe store the playlist in a registry branch..

Comment: When user install this software, and start it. He/She will be only need to play the video by click on play button. no browse needed for him/her. That`s why I want to set common path for video. My project path is by default in Partition D. and usually software install to Window contains Partition.

Comment: Then using `Application.StartupPath` like @Broken suggest in his answer is the way to go. simply keep the Exe and the video together..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import IO

```
Using System.IO;
```

then declare a string that will reference to your video folder
`string AbsoluteRef;`
use this code in your form load

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        AbsoluteRef = Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath + "\\..\\..\\Resources\\");
    }
    else
    {
        AbsoluteRef = Application.StartupPath + "\\Resources\\";
    }
```

Now declare a string for your video or which ever file like

```
string vlcvideo;
```

now add the two together

```
vlcvideo = AbsoluteRef & "myvideo.mp4";
```

Finnally add all this into your vlc plugin

```
axVLC.playlist.add(vlcvideo);
```

Complete Code looks like so.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;
using yournamespace.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace yourNameSpace
{

    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        string AbsoluteRef = null;

        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            AbsoluteRef = Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath + "\\..\\..\\Resources\\");
        }
        else
        {
            AbsoluteRef = Application.StartupPath + "\\Resources\\";
        }
        string vlcVideo = AbsoluteRef + "myvideo.mp4";
        axVLC.playlist.add(vlcvideo);

        }
```

Comment: Its too complected, can you please tell me whether put this code?

Comment: Ok I will add a screenshot

Comment: there is no problem in the code.but video does`t start when i press button play... I think the problem is in the path. I have added the path exactly which you provided

Comment: hmmm pause debugging and look at the path for the vlcvideo sometimes when you release or deploy an application the path is different also the way my path is set up is to accomedate the fact i am using a 64 bit system so my app runs in a different folder which is why i use one extra \\ so just check the string and correct it

Comment: also in visual studio switch it from debugging to release the path you see will be the path where the app is deployed and the video is located...